would this trigger a means plus function interpretation?
a computer implemented method comprising:
identifying a first value selected by a first user;

If the claim only includes this much detail regarding how the first value is generated, which is selected by the first user, would this trigger a means plus function interpretation?
There are various ways in which a user can select a value using a computer, such as drop down list selection, keyboard input, slider, etc.
Without being specific, would this trigger a means plus functions?
Questions:

But at the same time, there is nothing novel or non-obvious about a user selecting a value from a computer. Since this step itself is not what's novel, non-obvious about the invention, would this be enough detail?
What if in the future, someone invented any entire novel way for a user to select a value from a computer, such as brain control? If this person were to implement my invention with this new way of value selection, would they nonetheless still infringe?


To me, it's entirely unclear what it means for a computer to "identify" a value (without any context). If a claim term is not "free-standing" (it has sufficiently clear meaning without referencing the specification), it will have to have meaning imported from the specification one way or another (or be indefinite if the specification has no guidance). MPF is one way, acting as one's own lexicographer is another.

There is context, the first value is part of a larger data object that was received from the first user's device. But what about the "selected" part. It seems pretty common place for a user to select a value from a computer?
